# Trying to get a value within a value from JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm able to call an API and retrieve JSON data.

The following code returns dictionary objects:

```
 NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:ResponseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];


NSDictionary *hits = dataDictionary[@"hits"];

NSLog(@"%@", hits);
```

"hits" returns this data:

```
 {
    "_id" = 521b95cf4a56d006d578c213;
    "_index" = "f762ef22-e660-434f-9071-a10ea6691c27";
    "_score" = "3.6973438";
    "_type" = item;
    fields =         {
        "brand_id" = 513fbc1283aa2dc80c000005;
        "brand_name" = Subway;
        "item_id" = 521b95cf4a56d006d578c213;
        "item_name" = "6\" Subway Melt\U00ae";
        "nf_serving_size_qty" = 1;
        "nf_serving_size_unit" = serving;
    };
```

I'm attempting to get the "item_name" value, so I attempted it like so:

```
  NSString *nameOfItem = hits[@"item_name"];

NSLog(@"%@", nameOfItem);
```

However, I resulted in a SIGABRT error with the following message:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f97c0d85520'
```

How would I go about retrieving the "item_name" value?

Comment: sorry but this doesn't look a valid JSON. And anyway I see "item_name" under "fields"

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have an array, but what you show for hits is a dictionary. Is that the full printout from your log? Try logging [hits class] and see what that gives.

Comment: "hits" didn't return the data above.  There were `(  )` characters surrounding the data which you omitted in the above listing.  Learn how to read JSON!!!

Comment: (Of course, even if you didn't have that problem you're still doing it wrong.  Again, learn how to read JSON.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, from your error message it seems that your JSON output is an Array.

Either you should paste the entire JSON or a Sample structure of it.

Anyhow, by assuming that your JSON contains array of dictionaries and each dictionary has a key named `item_name` which points to another dictionary, in that case you can retrieve the value in this way.

```
NSString *nameOfItem = hits[indexOfDictionary][@"fields"][@"item_name"];
```

OR

```
NSString *nameOfItem = [[[hits objectAtIndex:indexOfDictionary] objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"item_name"];
```

As **Hot Licks** mentioned in the comments, you need to read more on how read JSON Data.

Answer (score -1):

This should get what you want.

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:ResponseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", [[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"hits"] objectForKey:@"fields"] valueForKey:@"item_name"]);
```